# What causes some keyboards to not be recognized and able to access the BIOS in post?

Tags: keyboard, bios

Why is it that some USB keyboards will allow you to access the BIOS menu like pushing F10 for example but others will not be responsive?

How do you know if the key board will or will not work?

And on another note do wireless keyboards work?

Comment: The only time I encountered a USB keyboard that had a problem as you described, it was connected to a front-panel USB port.  Connection to a rear-panel USB port was always problem free for about 4 different keyboards.  I've used two different wireless keyboards that have a USB receiver dongle without any issues.  Of course YMMV because of IR or RF reception issues.

Comment: Front/Back all the same in my testing with the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the back of the PC, plug the keyboard into the **top left USB port**.

> Some motherboards give priority to that slot.

**Note** : When i had this problem and googled most of the answer I got is that this might be an issue with CMOS. It can be fixed by taking out the CMOS battery to reset the BIOS.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to try that in my tests.